# Pandas Qcut, rounding values, Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a key for the qcut bins I have from my data set.

So below I have the data from the 'total' column into ten bins, I have dropped the duplicates and sorted the values so I can see what the bin values are and in order. The below has the bins without using 'precision'.

```
bin_key=pd.qcut(bin_key['Total'], 10).drop_duplicates().sort_values()
bin_key.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
bin_key
```

Output:

```
0           (11.199, 7932.26]
1        (7932.26, 15044.289]
2      (15044.289, 22709.757]
3      (22709.757, 32762.481]
4      (32762.481, 43491.146]
5       (43491.146, 55728.56]
6       (55728.56, 72823.314]
7     (72823.314, 100161.814]
8    (100161.814, 156406.846]
9    (156406.846, 1310448.18]
```

I want to round the values to the nearest thounsand. Using precision it looks like this:

```
bin_key=pd.qcut(bin_key['Total_Costs'], 10, 'precision=-3').drop_duplicates().sort_values()
bin_key.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
bin_key
```

Output

```
0        (-1000.0, 8000.0]
1        (8000.0, 15000.0]
2       (15000.0, 23000.0]
3       (23000.0, 33000.0]
4       (33000.0, 43000.0]
5       (43000.0, 56000.0]
6       (56000.0, 73000.0]
7      (73000.0, 100000.0]
8     (100000.0, 156000.0]
9    (156000.0, 1310000.0]
```

How can I round to 0 rather than -1000?